# weka.classifiers.neural.lvq Not found

Tags: weka, imagej, fiji

Where can i found lvq in weka dev 3.7.11 jar?
As while importing this weka.classifiers.neural.lvq, it shows me an error of not found.

Answer (score 0):

In the Weka Package Manager you have the LVQ clustering method, but I guess you refer to the classifier from this [site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wekaclassalgos/)?